# How to defer rendering of select component from material-ui

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, html-select

After upgrading to @material-ui/core 4.11.2, I got warnings with my select components. This is happens because data aren't available at the time I'm rendering the select.

You can see my issue on github: https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/24041

To correct that, `languages` need to be available before rendering the select component.

Now, I want to correct my code, but I'm totally lost, I don't know how to do that.

Here my select component:

```
<FormControl>
  <InputLabel htmlFor="lang">
    {localStorage.getItem("lang")}
  </InputLabel>
  <Select
    value={localStorage.getItem("lang")}
    onChange={e => this.changeLng(e.target.value, i18n)}
    inputProps={{name: "lang", id: "lang"}}
    >
    {languages &&
      languages.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
            {item.name}
          </MenuItem>
        );
    })}
  </Select>
</FormControl>
```

Below the `componentWillMount()`

```js
getLanguages.refetch({}).then(({ data }) => {
  if (data) {
    let langData = data && data.getLanguages;
      this.setState({
        languages: langData
      });
    }
});
```

Below also the `changeLng`

```
changeLng = (e, i18n) => {
    let arr = ["fr", "en"];
    let langList = e;
    let { categoryInfo, staticPagesTerms, productsInfo,AdvancedFilter } = this.props;
    localStorage.setItem("lang", e);
    if(AdvancedFilter && AdvancedFilter !== undefined){
        this.props.AdvancedFiltersubmit({
          fieldChild: [],
          rangeFilter: []
        });
    }
    localStorage.setItem("langList", e);
    staticPagesTerms.refetch().then(({ data }) => {});
    productsInfo.refetch({ filter: {} }).then(({ data }) => {
    })

    if (e === "fr") {
      document.body.setAttribute("dir", "ltr");
      localStorage.setItem("ltr", "ltr");
    } else {
      if (!arr.includes(e)) {
        langList = "en";
        localStorage.setItem("langList", e);
      } else {
        //localStorage.getItem("lang")
      }
      document.body.setAttribute("dir", "ltr");
      localStorage.setItem("ltr", "ltr");
    }
    i18n.changeLanguage(langList);
    this.props.getRefetch({ variables: { categoryRefetch: true } });
  };
```

Any idea how to solve this? Any answers will be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using `defaultValue=""` in the `<Select />` component like this comment on releated issues.
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/18494#issuecomment-718487022

or if it doesn't work try to provide the default MenuItem if `languages` data is not available yet. For example

```
{languages ? (
  languages.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
        {item.name}
      </MenuItem>
    );
  })) : (
    <MenuItem value="en">
      English
    </MenuItem>
  )
}
```

I used the value="en" and English as the default value, but you can adjust it with any static data.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I tried your 2 possibilities, but the warnings remains the same : 

`Material-UI: You have provided an out-of-range value fr for the select (name="lang") component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are "".`

Answer (score 0):

seems @vigor akbar answer is also not working, then another way is to delay the rendering of the whole `<Select>` component. Provide a demo `<Select>` component until you get the data of `languages`. And when `languages` is available then render that required component.

```
  <FormControl>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="lang">{localStorage.getItem("lang")}</InputLabel>
    {languages ? (
      <Select
        value={localStorage.getItem("lang")}
        onChange={(e) => this.changeLng(e.target.value, i18n)}
        inputProps={{ name: "lang", id: "lang" }}>
        {languages.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <MenuItem key={index} value={item.value}>
              {item.name}
            </MenuItem>
          );
        })}
      </Select>
    ) : (
       // Default element shown unitl the 'languages' isn't loaded
      <Select value={"loading"} placeholder="Loading...">
        <MenuItem value="loading">Loading....</MenuItem>
      </Select>
    )}
  </FormControl>
```

Comment: Thank very much for your time and to taking a look. Your source code works fine, but unfortunately it doesn't suppress the warnings from material-ui.

Comment: can you share a codesandbox of the issue? it'll be quite helpful to debug

Comment: The problem is that I am going to take informations in a database. I can send you the my page code, but I don't know how. And I can't post it here, it's too big.

Comment: then it's quite hard to debug without reproducing  the issue :(